# RequestScope introduces Classloader leak on TomEE 8 / OpenJDK 11

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, wildfly, apache-tomee, openejb

By tracing down a classloader leak in my TomEE webapp I created a minimalistic app (one JSF Page, one class) and realized, that this already creates a classloader leak.

Leaks are introduced for example when:
* enums are used
* certain lambdas are used (see code example)
* CDI scopes are used (see code example)
* a beans.xml is provided
* ...

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;

@Named   //  no leak
@RequestScoped  // introduces a leak!
public class PrincipalTest {

    public String userName() {
        return "User name from bean.";
    }

    // some lambdas will remain instanciate after app is stoped
    public List<String> names(){
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add("aaa");list.add("abb");list.add("acc");
        // this lambda implementation is fine:
        return list.stream()
                .filter(s -> s.startsWith("a"))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

          // this introduces a leak:
//        return list.stream()
//                .collect(Collectors.toList());        
    }
```

I'm substantially confused about this and feel like having no chance to ever get a 'real' app class-leaking free. What are your experiences?

Can anybody confirm this behavior? (I uploaded my test sources to https://1drv.ms/u/s!AlHB9FAlFWW_iLkHPeUguiu2HSZ8FA?e=2eiBHM - in case someboy likes to play with it.)

Comment: Can you describe the nature of the leak? Do you have application-created threads still running? Do you have thread-local values bound to request-processing threads? Have you registered an application-loaded object/class in a global registry of any kind?

Comment: Mabe I wasn't clear enough in my question: There is only a single class in the app, the one shown above. No created threads, no other libraies (except the ones that come with tomee). I start, load the startpage of the app (which displays the name properties) and then stop the app (via tomcat manager). After stopping no classes of the webapps classpath should be loaded any more, but in the profiler I can find one instance of leaktest.PrincipalTest$$Lambda$363#1 still living on the heap.

Comment: Replacing the lambda by simply returning the list will result in no instances beeing loaded after stop but still two classes are loaded: leaktest.PrincipalTest and leaktest.PrincipalTest$$OwbNormalScopeProxy0. So even this causes a classloader leak. I can reduce the class even more and will end with the fact that once an instance is created (even without any function in the class) its class can not be unloaded. It looks like the auto-created ProxyInstance introduces the leak.

Comment: This in turn would mean that there it is impossible to use CDI with TomEE without introducing a classloader leakage. But I doubt that this is the case?

Comment: So you tried this on GlassFish (or the likes) or WildFly and it does not happen there? And what about tomee7?

Comment: I only tried this on TomEE plume 8.0.0 with OpenJDK 11  (Eventually I will try on WildFly in some time, but I'd rather like not to switch the platform as this usually is not trivial.)

Comment: You seem to have a [mcve] so trying that on another platform (tomee 7 comes to mind) should not be too difficult. Maybe it is even a plain bug in the jdk?

Comment: I have now tested on WildFly 18 with OpenJDK11 and 12. Basically the same results, but the increase in leaking classes per reload seems a bit smaller (just by visual observation of the profiler graphs).

Comment: It becomes clearer that adding a Scope (@RequestScoped) produces the problem. Investigating TomEEs WebAppClassLoader CG Roots of a leftover ClassLoader, I find references to classLoaderinorg.apache.openejb.AppContext#4 > val$appContextinorg.apache.openejb.cdi.ThreadSingletonServiceImpl$1#2 > executorinjavax.enterprise.event.ImmutableNotificationOptions#2 > defaultNotificationOptionsinorg.apache.webbeans.event.NotificationManager#2  > ... > this$0inorg.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor#1 [GC root - Java frame]

Comment: That lambda must be stopping class-unloading for a reason. It's not just because lambdas break JVMs. Can you track the object references back to a live object or thread?

Comment: Actually not, there is only a single custom class in the test webapp (no created threads), and this in not instanciated any more after application stop. Some Lambas will however increase the number of uncollectable classes, but the real problem seems to be the @RequestScoped annotation. To me it looks like openejb.AppContex keeps a reference to any RequestScoped class. If AppContext for any reason is loaded by the 'SystemClassLoader', than it would explain why no scoped class can be collected.

It should be trivial to reproduce the problem on TomEE. I wonder if anybody can try to do so?